# After M1 to M2 Migration Salable Qty Empty

Tags: magento2

Add **`inventory_stock_1`** Table, Show product Out of stock

[image]

Comment: Have you tried select products and assign them to inventory source? You can also do that via System > Import.
Edit : read about multisource inventory here https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-merchant-type.html

Answer (score 1):

There should be view for `inventory_stock_1` like this https://prnt.sc/pr4jv4

check if it is accessible if not delete it and run below snippet in your mysql console to update inventory data.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`DATABASE_USER`@`DATABASE_HOST` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`  AS  select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)));
```