# How to re save all products in Magneto 2

Tags: magento2

I'm Using this below Script, but on executing my page lands to `Error 503`.

Can anyone, please help me in re-saving all the product programmatically

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productcollection = $productCollectionFactory->create()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->load();

foreach ($productcollection as $product) {
    $productId = $product->getId();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $product->load($productId);
    $product->save();
}
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: where you are executing this script server (or) local instance? use exception handling try and catch in your logic so that you can get the exact error it may help you further.

Comment: do the changes https://prnt.sc/pqmm7e

Comment: Ok i will try once

Comment: Sir can you answer some of my other question

Comment: But let me know why you would like to save all the products programmatically? Is this like trail (or) you want to perform on server level?

Comment: See below URL:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294200/after-m1-to-m2-migration-salable-qty-empty

Comment: I have answered please verify end to end after executed script from your end. Please let me know if you facing any issues immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code in which i executed locally to save all the simple products programmatically. Make sure to take a **Database** backup before executing this script & Execute this script from the M2 root folder from the command line & don't forget to re-index. If it works locally while testing. Do the appropriate changes if required based on your requirements.

(or else) save one product programmatically and check the results whether it is working (or) not.

```
<? php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 80000);
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');


$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productcollection = $productCollectionFactory->create()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->load();
echo "Total Products".$productcollection->getSize().'\r';                      
foreach ($productcollection as $product) {
    if($product->getTypeId() == 'simple'){
        $productId = $product->getId();
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $product->load($productId);
        $product->save();
        echo "product saved successfully -".$product->getId().'\r';
    }

   }
?>
```

Comment: executing Your script Error:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 33554440 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/Exm.com/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291

Comment: How many products are there?

Comment: 10852 records found

Comment: Use ini_set('memory_limit','10G');

Comment: Are you executing the above script on the local instance environment? (or) server?

Comment: executing In Server

Comment: Server Error
503
Service Temporarily Unavailable

Comment: Did you take DB to back up before executing the script?

Comment: Yes i have backup

Comment: @RanjeetSingh are you able to execute PHP script earlier from magento2 root folder if not please execute the sample php code from pub folder. and check it  whether you are able to execute sample PHP program or not

Comment: Ok wait sir ...

Comment: Please let me know still whether you are facing the issue or not?

Comment: Help: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294286/after-migration-inventory-source-item-table-is-empty-magneto-2

Comment: @RanjeetSingh is this issue has been resolved?

Comment: Hello sir Can you help me other Que. ?