# After Migration inventory_source_item table is empty magneto 2

Tags: magento2, catalog, migration, cataloginventory

This Table **`( inventory_source_item )`** is Empty and which all my product show out of stock, Can anyone, please help me solve this issue

[image]

Comment: Let me know as per your requirement whether you want to migrate catalog data?

Comment: Thank you for reply my error is solve

Comment: let me know what is the issue plz

Comment: (inventory_source_item) this table is empty after migration and show all my products is out of stock

Comment: You can import CSV with stock status to resolve this issue.

Comment: @NIPPU sir after login in site and add product in cart coming error (.We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now.) this any idea how to solve it

Comment: Have you posted your question on the stack? if yes, please share me the link with the details included with the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to build out the `inventory_source_item` table based on the legacy `cataloginventory_stock_status` table:

```
INSERT into `inventory_source_item`
(source_code, sku, quantity, status)
SELECT 'default', sku, qty, stock_status FROM (`cataloginventory_stock_status` as `lg` JOIN `catalog_product_entity` as `prd` on((`lg`.`product_id` = `prd`.`entity_id`)))
```